# Where does the expression 'Babbies first ...' come from?

Tags: etymology

I assume the expression is derived from "baby's first ...". I have seen the expression used mainly for online discussions of 'geeky' or 'nerdy' stuff. A quick google search gives me: babbies first linux, babbies first wallhack.

The usage of the expression seems to be intentional (e.g. not due to a typo). The gentoo wiki -- which has good reputation -- has a 'babbies first linux' page.

Comment: @WS2 [Scots isn’t ‘slang’](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/dost/babby) nor are dialects.

Comment: I never heard 'babbies' when I grew up in Scotland. It was always 'weans' and 'bairns' in both the Highlands and in Glasgow. [The Scotsman](https://www.scotsman.com/lifestyle/culture/books/scottish-word-of-the-week-weans-and-bairns-1-3220599).

Comment: @Spagirl I take your point, but is it slang or is it dialect? Where does one end and the other start? OED sense 1b of *slang* is: *The special vocabulary or phraseology of a particular calling or profession; the cant or jargon of a certain class or period.* It doesn't actually refer to regional dialects, but I think it is splitting hairs to exclude them. But ok "slang" wasn't the best word for me to have used. Note I said it was "long-established".

Comment: @WS2 Well given that I linked you to the Dictionary of the Scots Language with a usage dated to 1513 in a translation of Virgil to Scots I’d personally go for it being a regional dialect of the Scots language. It doesn’t fit your quoted definition of slang or the OED’s sense 1c.

Comment: @Spagirl Ok. I concede the point. I will delete my comment and replace it with a differently worded one.

Comment: "Babbies" is Scots dialect dating from at least the sixteenth-century - for "babies". It is alive and well today in Scotland and to some extent in northern England.

Answer (score 2):

It's a reference to a meme popular amongst Reddit users and other online forum users.

[From Knowyourmeme.com](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-is-babby-formed)

> How Is Babby Formed refers to a popular question posed to the Yahoo! Answers forum about how humans reproduce. The question is known for its awkward phrasing and misspelling of the word "baby." The phrase became a popular source of YouTube remixes, as well as its frequent use as a copypasta.
>
> In 2006, Yahoo! Answers user kavya posted the question "how is babby formed? How girl get pragnent?" The most famous answer is also infamous for misspelling and grammatical errors. It reads:
>
> "They need to do way instain mother> who kill thier babbys, becuse these babby cant fright back? It was on the news this mroing a mother in ar who had kill her three kids, they are taking the three babby back to new york too lady to rest. my pary are with the father who lost his chrilden ; i am truley sorry for your lots"
>
> On November 26th, 2006, Something Awful user Johnny "Doc Evil" Titanium posted a series of screenshots from Yahoo! Answers in a round up called "Yahoo! Answers Revisted." Included in this entry was kavya's post.
> Several months later, on February 5th, 2007, Something Awful user Dave "Shmorky" Kelly included the post, as dramatized by a SA forum member, in his "Flash Tub" animation, along with other favorite Weekend Web posts. "kavya" was rendered as a gruff-voiced caveman.
> On March 7th, 2008, Urban Dictionary user mobrien118 posted a definition of the word "babby." Within nine years, the post ... has received more than 1,000 upvotes.

[image: Babby]

Usually the preferred spelling is "babby's" and not "babbies".

Comment: "Source: trust me dude" that's not what a source is.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to ELU. Your *linked* source material is actually somewhat convincing.  Your quoted source: trust me dude, is not. The meme as a source is actually a pretty reasonable supposition.  Links tend to expire, so it's best to copy some of what your link shows into your answer. Fix this answer and be welcomed to the community.